# Does Ruby have an addon similar to Perl 6 grammars?

Tags: regex, ruby, grammar, raku

Perl has been one of my go-to programming language tools for years and years. Perl 6 grammars looks like a great language feature. I'd like to know if someone has started something like this for Ruby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. And, since Perl6 grammars are a *language* feature, and Ruby doesn't allow the language to be extended, it is actually *impossible* to implement this in an "addon".

However, there are numerous libraries for Ruby which implement different kinds of Parsing or Grammar Systems. The standard library already contains `racc`, which is an LALR(1) parser generator (comparable to and somewhat compatible with the venerable `yacc`). Then there is the [ANTLR](http://AnTLR.Org/) parser generator, which has a Ruby backend (although I am not sure whether that actually works).

The closest thing to Perl6 grammars in Ruby would be the [Ruby-OMeta project](https://GitHub.Com/Aquasync/Ruby-OMeta/) (make sure to also take a look at [Ryan Davis's fork](https://GitHub.Com/ZenSpider/Ruby-OMeta/)), which unfortunately ist still under development. (Or rather, no longer under active development.)

So, keeping to stuff that actually *exists*, I recommend you take a look at the [Grammar project](https://RubyForge.Org/projects/grammar/) and [Treetop](http://Treetop.RubyForge.Org/).

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use actual Perl 6 grammars in Ruby, your best bet is going to be [Cardinal](http://github.com/cardinal/cardinal), a ruby compiler on Parrot.  It's currently unfinished and VERY SLOW, but I'm quite hopeful about it being a viable ruby implementation eventually.  It's currently mostly-inactive, pending some infrastructure changes in Parrot to support improved parsing speed and additional features.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know of anything similar for Ruby.

However there is something similar for Perl5, see [`Regexp::Grammars`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Grammars/)